# how to save kartik editable yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app, kartik-v

I have a problem with editable kartik, how can I make editable kartik stored in the database? sometimes BAD REQUEST notifications appear

My Controller

```
public function actions()
{
    return ArrayHelper::merge ( parent::actions () , [
        'editable' => [
            'class' => EditableColumn::className() ,
            'modelClass' => AssetMasterRequest::className() ,
            'forceCreate'=> false,
        ]

    ]);
}
```

My View

```
    <?php
$gridColumns = [
    'assetMaster.asset_name',
    'request_date',
    [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute' => 'requested_by',
        'pageSummary' => 'Total',
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'width' => '210px',
        'editableOptions' =>  function ($model, $key, $index) use ($ambildata) {
            return [
                'header' => 'Request By',
                'formOptions' => ['action'=>'pru'] ,
                'size' => 'md',
                'afterInput' => function ($form, $widget) use ($model, $index) {
                    return $form->field($model, "request_notes");
                }
            ];
        }
    ],
    [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\EditableColumn',
        'attribute' => 'request_notes',
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'width' => '210px',
        'editableOptions' =>[
            'formOptions'=>[
                'action'=>'editable'
            ],
        ]

    ],
    'requested_by',
];?>
```

Please help. Have spent two days on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must return a JSON encoded response in the array format specified above with output and message values. This is important for the AJAX request to be processed and completed successfully.

Here is a grid view configuration   with editable column

```
echo GridView::widget([
    'id' => 'kv-grid-demo',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => $gridColumns, // check the configuration for grid columns by clicking button above
    'containerOptions' => ['style' => 'overflow: auto'], // only set when $responsive = false
    'headerRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'filterRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'pjax' => true, // pjax is set to always true for this demo
    // set your toolbar
    'toolbar' =>  [
        [
            'content' =>
                Html::button('<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>', [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success',
                    'title' => Yii::t('kvgrid', 'Add Book'),
                    'onclick' => 'alert("This will launch the book creation form.\n\nDisabled for this demo!");'
                ]) . ' '.
                Html::a('<i class="fas fa-redo"></i>', ['grid-demo'], [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-outline-secondary',
                    'title'=>Yii::t('kvgrid', 'Reset Grid'),
                    'data-pjax' => 0, 
                ]), 
            'options' => ['class' => 'btn-group mr-2']
        ],
        '{export}',
        '{toggleData}',
    ],
    'toggleDataContainer' => ['class' => 'btn-group mr-2'],
    // set export properties
    'export' => [
        'fontAwesome' => true
    ],
    // parameters from the demo form
    'bordered' => $bordered,
    'striped' => $striped,
    'condensed' => $condensed,
    'responsive' => $responsive,
    'hover' => $hover,
    'showPageSummary' => $pageSummary,
    'panel' => [
        'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
        'heading' => $heading,
    ],
    'persistResize' => false,
    'toggleDataOptions' => ['minCount' => 10],
    'exportConfig' => $exportConfig,
    'itemLabelSingle' => 'book',
    'itemLabelPlural' => 'books'
]);
```

Comment: can you give an example to my code? where should I save it